# Illegal invocation error (if processData not set and can not find action handler if set) on ajax request in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, form-data

Sorry for bad title. I dont understand why I get an `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` error on my AJAX request in wordpress.

This code **works**:

JS

```
function updateDB(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'det_lilla_exta
        },
    });
}
```

PHP (server script)

```
<?php

add_action('wp_ajax_det_lilla_extra', 'det_lilla_extra');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_det_lilla_extra', 'det_lilla_extra' );
function det_lilla_extra(){

    echo "hi";

}
```

But If I change my js (to later be able to send images via the fromdata object)

JS

```
function updateDB(){
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('action', 'det-lilla-extra');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
    });
}
```

Then I get the `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` error. I have done some googleing and found out that to prevent your data to be converted to a string you should put the `processData` parameter to false. Like done here:

```
function updateDB(){
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('action', 'det-lilla-extra');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        processData: false
    });
}
```

But now I only recieve `0` from my wordpress php script which means that it can not find my `action` handler.

So Im not sure what to do here. Or what is really being wrong. Any ideas?

(I might have some slight syntax errors here since I have not copy pasted my code, but I do **not** have any syntax related errors in my original code).

Comment: Try to set the `contentType` parameter to **false**

Comment: @Wizard Tried that already. No change.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was not icluding `enctype: 'multipart/form-data',`

```
//update database with posted values
function updateDB(){

    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('action', 'det_lilla_extra');
    fd.append('image', $('#fileInput').prop('files')[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: fd,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        contentType:false,
        processData:false,
    });
};
```

This should be a working solution for sending images via an ajax request in wordpress.

Comment: I don't see a parameter `enctype` in jQuery $.ajax ... The `enctype="multipart/form-data"` should be put in the `<form>` tag.